# Good open source web app using Servlets/JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good quality open source web application that uses Servlets/JSP. Reason for this is that I'm currently maintaining a web application and it doesn't look like it was designed properly. I'm a junior developer so I don't have a lot of experience with this and I don't have a mentor to teach me. Some bad design choices (I think) are:

- All controllers must extend a class called `Controller` which **forces** you to override **both** doGet and doPost
- A singleton database class that connects to a database using JNDI. Compiler warns me that this is deprecated.
- Messy error pages. From what I've read, I could set all the error pages using the DD.
- A Model class that extends HashMap and it's using completely raw types (ugh!)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/releases/petstore/

Comment: All controllers must extend a class called Controller which forces you to override both doGet and doPost - if you really consider that an issue, create 2 classes - AbstractGetController and AbstractPostController - each of which leaves only one of the methods as abstract and either delegates the other or throws an excpetion. Then everyone can extend these as needed. So that's a Very Minor issue.

Comment: A Model class that extends HashMap and it's using completely raw types (ugh!) - yes that does sound ugly. To be fair this app might have been developed pre generics (JDK 1.4 or earlier)

Answer (score 1):

There's an [Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/tutorials-137605.html) with Java EE tutorials on it for versions 3 through 6.

Those tutorials will have good sections on Servlets/JSP in them that can be referenced and used.

There's a lot of information there but the individual sections are helpful too (have personally consulted individual sections many times and have found it very helpful).